# Initializing attributes in Ruby objects

Tags: ruby, arrays, initialization

I create a new object of type Spam, with attr_accessor to both hooray and name and I have the initialize method. I'm expecting when I create a new object the object is loaded with a var of name with "Whammy" and a empty array named hooray. Though I'm not getting this behavior. Can anyone explain, thank you in advance.

```
module Test
class Spam
 attr_accessor :hooray, :name

 def initialize
    hooray = []
    name = "Whammy"
 end
end 
end

Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.0)
irb(main):001:0> require 'Test'
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> test = Test::Spam.new
=> #<Test::Spam:0x000000031ff470>
irb(main):003:0> test.name
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> test.hooray
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> test.hooray << 5
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<
    from (irb):5
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
irb(main):006:0>
```

Comment: `Test` is probably not a good module name, because Test::Unit has `Test` as a module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use instance variables inside an instance of a class to define attributes, not a local variable. local variables will go out of scope as soon as the method is finished executing. the code below should be more along the lines of what you need:

```
module Test
class Spam
 attr_accessor :hooray, :name

 def initialize
    @hooray = []
    @name = "Whammy"
 end
end 
end
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that you are trying to use the setters directly within the `initialize` method, but Ruby interprets this as creating local variables, not calling the setters on `self`.

```
 def initialize
    hooray = []
    name = "Whammy"
 end
```

You can work around this in one of two ways; set the attributes directly, such as `@attribute`:

```
 def initialize
    @hooray = []
    @name = "Whammy"
 end
```

Or if you really want to go through the setters (for instance, if you have custom setters which do something interesting), make it explicit with `self.setter`:

```
 def initialize
    self.hooray = []
    self.name = "Whammy"
 end
```